# check that a method of f exists for any child type of T in Julia

Tags: types, julia

Say I have a family of functions all defined on a particular concrete type `CT <: T` and when I see one such function in the wild I would like to check whether a method indeed exists for any subtype of the abstract type `T`

I thought I could go something like this but apparently not

```
f(x::Float64) = x^2 
hasmethod(f,Tuple{Float64})
true    
hasmethod(f,Tuple{<:Number}) 
false
```

ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a starting point:

```
function isdef(::typeof(f), ::Type{T}) where {T}
    for m in methods(f)
        if Tuple{typeof(f), T} <: m.sig
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end
```

Or

```
isdef(::typeof(f), ::Type{T}) where {T} = any(Tuple{typeof(f), T} <: m.sig for m in methods(f))
```

It's not ideal, since it access the internal field `:sig` and maybe there's a better and more general way to determine subtype relationship, but it works for your example, and in terms of performance, it is 170,000 times faster than `allsubtypes(Number)`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the need, but you could recursively enumerate all subtypes<sup>1</sup>,

```
function allsubtypes(T; r = Type[])
    if isconcretetype(T)
        return r
    else
        st = subtypes(T)
        append!(r, st)
        for U in st
            append!(r, allsubtypes(U))
        end
        return r
    end
end
```

and then just check:

```
any(hasmethod(f, Tuple{T}) for T in allsubtypes(Number))
```

---

<sup>1</sup>This doesn't work with `Union` or union-all types, though. `subtypes` just ignores that case.

Comment: Thanks ! I was hoping to not have to check all subtypes manually but this would do. The 'need' is that I have `f` as a field in a struct and wanted to check its signature in the constructor, so as to catch at initialization if I'm passing the wrong function.